# It takes two to tango

Tags: translation, idiom

Last night as I was talking about idioms in Korean, a question came up about the English expression "It takes two to tango." Is there a Korean equivalent to this idiom?

If it does exist, how common is it? (I.e. Did you just read it in a book, or have you actually heard a Korean use it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a Korean equivalent to this idiom?

Yes. The most popular one is "[외손뼉이 울랴](http://krdic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=%EC%99%B8%EC%86%90%EB%BC%89%EC%9D%B4%20%EC%9A%B8%EB%9E%B4&kind=all) (Literally) One hand can't cry, One hand can't make a (clapping) sound" among the following idioms.

> [속담] **외손뼉이 울랴**  (표제어:외손뼉)
>   1.[같은 속담] 외손뼉이 소리 날까.
>   2.[같은 속담] 외손뼉이 소리 날까.
>
> [속담] **외손뼉이 울지 못한다**  (표제어:외손뼉)
>   1.[같은 속담] 외손뼉이 소리 날까.
>   2.[같은 속담] 외손뼉이 소리 날까.
>
> [속담] **외손뼉이 못 울고 한 다리로 가지 못한다**   (표제어:외손뼉)
>   1.[같은 속담] 외손뼉이 소리 날까.

It is also written as "외손뼉이 소리 날까". They are traditional versions of "손뼉도 마주쳐야 소리가 난다" which is easier to understand and use.

> If it does exist, how common is it? (I.e. Did you just read it in a
>   book, or have you actually heard a Korean use it?)

It is very common. You can read and hear it quite often.

Answer (score 5):

손뼉도 마주쳐야 소리가 난다 *one hand can't clap alone*

I'd say it's pretty common, no native won't recognize it.